# How to add local folder path of ubuntu folder in appsettings.json of webapi project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have to access files in `webapi` project. When I do development in windows, I have added path of local folder in appsettigs.json as below

```
"AppSettings": {
    "fileLocation": "D:\\files"
  }
```

I have deploy this application to ubuntu, and I have stored all files which I want to read on location `/usr/bin/application/files`

so I have modified my appsettings.json as below

```
"AppSettings": {
        "fileLocation": "/usr/bin/application/files"
      }
```

But seems this does not work, when I tried to call api, it is giving `500 Internal Server Error`

am I adding file path of ubuntu folder correctly?

Answer (score 0):

If you need relative to your application path you can use this:

```
var path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "files", "file.ext");
```

[AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.basedirectory?view=net-7.0) is folder of executing .exe/.dll (application root folder)

[Path.Combine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=net-7.0) will build you path suitable for environment's OS.